# MySQL error 1215 Cannot add Foreign key constraint - FK in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

im new on mysql workbench, and i tried so many things to put my script working but i simply cant... Ive got these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Utilizador (email varchar(40) not null, nome varchar(50) 
not null,  dataNascimento date,  profissao varchar(50) not null,      
reputacao double(3,2) unsigned not null, constraint pk_Utilizador     
primary key(email))
```

This is the first table created!

```
CREATE TABLE POI (email varchar(40) not null,  designacaoPOI
varchar(10) not null,  coordenadaX int,  coordenadaY int, 
descricaoPOI varchar(200), constraint pk_POI primary key(email,
designacaoPOI), constraint fk_POI foreign key(email) references
Utilizador(email) on delete cascade)
```

This is the second table created!

```
CREATE TABLE Utilizador_POI (email varchar(40) not null, designacaoPOI
varchar(10) not null, constraint pk_Utilizador_POI primary key(email,
designacaoPOI), constraint fk1_Utilizador_POI foreign key(email)
references Utilizador(email) on delete cascade,  constraint
fk2_Utilizador_POI foreign key(designacaoPOI) references
POI(designacaoPOI) on delete cascade)
```

This table gives me the error: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

I did some tests and im almost sure that the problem is in the foreign key "designacaoPOI". The other FK ("email") dont give me any error, so maybe the problem is in the Table POI?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is twofold:

**1/ Use `ID`s for `PRIMARY KEY`s**

You should be using `ID`s for primary keys rather than `VARCHAR`s or anything that has any real-world "business meaning". If you want the `email` to be unique within the `Utilizador`  table, the combination of `email` and `designacaoPOI` to be unique in the `POI` table, and the same combination (`email` and `designacaoPOI`) to be unique in `Utilizador_POI`, you should be using `UNIQUE KEY` constraints rather than `PRIMARY KEY` constraints.

**2/ You cannot `DELETE CASCADE` on a `FOREIGN KEY` that doesn't reference the `PRIMARY KEY`**

In your third table, `Utilizador_POI`, you have two `FOREIGN KEY`s references `POI`. Unfortunately, the `PRIMARY KEY` on `POI` is a composite key, so MySQL has no idea how to handle a `DELETE CASCADE`, as there is not a one-to-one relationship between the `FOREIGN KEY` in `Utilizador_POI` and the `PRIMARY KEY` of `POI`.

If you change your tables to all have a `PRIMARY KEY` of `ID`, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (
   id    INT(9)    AUTO_INCREMENT    NOT NULL
   ....
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you can reference each table by `ID`, and both your `FOREIGN KEY`s and `DELETE CASCADE`s will work.

Comment: You are actually right! We tried again making the model for the database, and after using more IDs, and actually making the right decisions, we had 0 errors on implementating the tables. So thanks a lot. I guess it was some noob mistakes

Comment: re "You should be using IDs for primary keys rather than VARCHARs or anything that has any real-world " Primary keys need to be 1)unique, 2) guaranteed to exist for every record, 3) guaranteed to never change. Something like an email address violates atleast the third point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `Utilizador_POI.email` references `POI.email`, which *itself* references `Utilizador.email`. MySQL is probably upset at the double-linking.

Also, since there seems to be a many-to-many relationship between `Utilizador` and `POI`, I think the structure of `Utilizador_POI` isn't what you really want. Instead, `Utilizador_POI` should reference a primary key from `Utilizador`, and a matching primary key from `POI`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second table. Your primary key is (email,designacaoPOI), when you try to reference that in your  table it gives you error because of this:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

For it to work, either change the order of your second tale PRIMARY KEY :

```
CREATE TABLE POI (
  email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  designacaoPOI VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  coordenadaX INT,
  coordenadaY INT,
  descricaoPOI VARCHAR(200),
  CONSTRAINT pk_POI PRIMARY KEY (designacaoPOI,email),  -- changed the order
  CONSTRAINT fk_POI FOREIGN KEY (email) 
     REFERENCES Utilizador(email) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61d09)</kbd>

or add an index for designacaoPOI:

```
CREATE TABLE POI (
  email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  designacaoPOI VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  coordenadaX INT,
  coordenadaY INT,
  descricaoPOI VARCHAR(200),
  CONSTRAINT pk_POI PRIMARY KEY (designacaoPOI,email),
  KEY key_designacaoPOI(designacaoPOI),  -- added index for that column
  CONSTRAINT fk_POI FOREIGN KEY (email) 
     REFERENCES Utilizador(email) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61d09)</kbd>

Either of these solutions will let you create your third table without errors.